# word for looking at other place while thinking something

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

When someone is thinking something hard, he might be looking somewhere else rather than at one whom he is talking. Which word/phrase can I use for describing his behaviour?

Answer (score 6):

You might say that "he stared off into space", or that "his eyes glazed over", or that "his eyes focused on nothing" while he thought.

Comment: +1 for "he stared off into space." A variation would be "he spaced out." If we wanted a single word, we could simply use _distracted_.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

- [**abstracted**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/abstracted) - *not giving attention to what is happening around you because you are thinking about something else*
- [**oblivious**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/oblivious) - *not conscious of something, especially what is happening around you*
- [**be miles away**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-miles-away) - *to not be conscious of what is happening around you because you are thinking about something else*
- [**in a world of your own**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/in-a-world-of-your-own) (*in another world*) - *thinking your own thoughts and ideas and not giving much attention to what is happening around you; not giving much attention to what is happening around you, because you are thinking about something else*
- [**have a faraway look**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/faraway-look) - *If you have a faraway expression, you look as though you are not thinking about what is happening around you; an expression that makes you appear to be thinking about something completely different from what is going on around you*

Answer (score 0):

a better more appropriate word would be "Zoned out" - Zoned out can also mean lost in thought. ex: We were discussing the report but he zoned out for a brief moment and exclaimed "Ah! I've got it!!".

Comment: Not bad, though it sort of implies he wasn't thinking anything or if he was it had nothing to do with the conversation.

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well. See the [Submitting Answers that merely answer the question](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1117) discussion on meta.